# How can I change the size of the innermost circle in a plotly sunburst?

Tags: python, plot, graphics, plotly, plotly-python

I want to achieve [this result](https://bl.ocks.org/maybelinot/5552606564ef37b5de7e47ed2b7dc099) but with plotly sunburst.

I can not find any parameter that controls the inner circle diameter in the documentation. It is any way to achieve that?

Comment: I believe someone previously asked this question, and I provided [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65029323/is-there-a-way-to-vary-the-thickness-of-a-layer-in-sunburst-diagram-in-plotly) which I believe is still true. On stackoverflow, duplicate questions are typically closed so there aren't too many open questions. But if the question and answer I linked to isn't the same question as yours, I'll retract my close vote

Comment: Oh yes, it is quite similar. Although the question you linked Is a more complex one, I believe that your answer (kudos for you) there could be useful to this one too. I agree, I will close this question by the end o the day if no one else has another answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can set only `root_color`. There is  no attribute `root_size`. Just print `help(go.sunburst.Root)`.